# How to fetch Rapidapi in laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, unirest, rapidapi

I am trying to fetch API using unirest in my laravel application. I followed all the steps given in the docs but it's showing me an error. If there is a better alternative for `unirest` please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Here is my controller,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        Love::create(
            request()->validate([
                'name_1' => ['required','max:255'],
                'name_2' => ['required','max:255'],
            ],
            [
                'name_1.required' => 'You have to Enter Your name',
                'name_2.required' => 'You have to Enter Your Crush name'
            ]));

            $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');

            $response = Unirest\Request::post("API_URL",
              array(
                "X-RapidAPI-Key" => "API_KEY"
              )
            );
                dd($response);

            return view("result");
   }
```

**Error**

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Unirest\Request' not found

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the `Unirest\Request` class.

```php
<?php

namespace Your\Namespace;

use Unirest\Request;

class YourClass{
...
```

If you don't import it, it will by default look for the class in the current namespace (in your case, `App\Http\Controllers`).